# Where to copy autoinstall.yaml file in iso image in Ubuntu 20.04 for auto installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.04

I am trying to do an unattended install of Ubuntu 20.04.
I am mounting the ISO image from the root directory.
I am updating the grubfile under /etc/grub.d/40_custom to update the boot loader.
So when I reboot, I get the installer menu and I could go till the language and other selection.

But it is failing at block probing as the mounted partition of the ISO image is still not unmounted.

Installation goes fine if I manually unmount the partition by the below command.
#losetup -d /dev/loop0
#umount -lfd /isodevice

I want this command to be executed before I do anything in the new installation.

So I found this link, https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference

I am adding early commands in /autoinstall.yaml the iso file but it's not reflected in the booted file structure.

So Where can I place this autoinstall.yaml file in ISO image and how to make the early commands gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a directory (for example cidata) and in side two cloud-init format (YAML) files meta-data and user-data.  The ubuntu format is detailed https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

Then you build your cidata ISO image as..

sudo genisoimage  -output cidata.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock cidata/*

Then you install that on a USB drive..
e.g.
sudo dd bs=64m if=cidata.iso of=/dev/

Then when the 20.04/20.10 installer boots up it will read the drive automaticly and use its settings..